# htaccess to deny access to the current directory?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I'd like to deny access to directory /foo/secret.

If I create a .htaccess file in /foo/secret, with...

```
<Directory ./>
        Order deny,Allow
        Deny from all
</Directory>
```

...I get a "500 Internal Server Error", which, while achieving the intended result, isn't the "403 Forbidden" message I was expecting.

I know you're supposed to put an absolute path in `Directory` directives but I'm committing this into a code repository and the remote client won't necessarily be running in the same path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't add `<Directory ./>` directive.
.htaccess points to the directory itself. At least, that worked for me...

Comment: Perfect. Looks like my apache skills are rusty... thanks!

Comment: Don't give up! Practice makes perfect. P.S. Why not mask the answer as correct? ;)

Comment: Why HUB, you just answered so quickly, Superuser wouldn't let me mark it as correct! :)

Comment: You'd better put the correct content, but not some modifications

Answer (score 1):

`.htaccess` files are already *in* a directory, so that directive is non-applicable. Just skip it and go straight to your directives.